# Python on PyCharm crashes with 'Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)'

Tags: python, python-3.x, crash

## Crash in PyCharm

Following code will crash with Python3 on PyCharm.

```
import locale
import logging
import logging.handlers

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_CH.UTF-8')

stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
logger.error('testing')
```

The code should print `testing`.

PyCharm will crash and print the exit code:

> Python crashes with 'Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)'

Tested under Windows 10 - 10.0.17134 Build 17134, Python 3.6.3.

## Crash on Windows Cmd

I've also tested it under **Windows** **CMD** with:

```
c:\Python361\python.exe -c "import locale; import logging; import logging.handlers; locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_CH.UTF-8'); stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(); stream_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')); logger = logging.getLogger(__name__); logger.addHandler(stream_handler); logger.error('testing')"
```

Which **should** print `testing` but ends without any output. I have also test it with Python 3.7.3 on the Windows CMD with the same result.

## Crash on Python IDLE

I've also tested the code with Python 3.6.1 on **IDLE**:

```
import locale; import logging; import logging.handlers; locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_CH.UTF-8'); stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(); stream_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')); logger = logging.getLogger(__name__); logger.addHandler(stream_handler); logger.error('testing')
```

Which prints

> 'de_CH.UTF-8'
>
> =============================== RESTART: Shell ===============================

[image: Python 3.6.1 IDLE Shell with crash]

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution following the python issue page here

https://bugs.python.org/issue36792#msg342966

Changing

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_CH.UTF-8')
```

to

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de-CH')
```

solves the problem.

Comment: Is this an answer to your question, or a question inside your question? Is your problem related to finding a source to that error, or have you found it? You fixed it simply by commenting random lines of code? Can you provide a summary to what is the purpose of that code?

Comment: @LucasWieloch The solution is halve-assed and I'm unhappy with it myself. Since it temporarly solve my case (using windows 10) I posted it so other might also temporarly help their problem. I'm putting all I know here on the table. Why do you downvote my answer?

Comment: @MadMiker I think it is quite an interesting question, I am curious to know what happened and what does this workaround has to do with it that error. I downvoted your answer because it doesn't seem that you could even find what your problem is, so how can you tell me that this answers it? You could have added your workaround to your question to help us understand what is happening there and find a proper answer, not only to you but to others that might face the same problem in the future

Comment: @LucasWieloch I guess this isn't the right place to discuss on how to handle the situation where someone has a question and some halve-solution. I'd suggest to discuss this on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I removed it not because you asked but because you earned it. With this answer I can grasp why you got the error and why this solution works, well done.

Comment: @LucasWieloch I've brought up the question how to ask a question with a halve-solution on meta here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387129/